# How to send messages over a closed WiFi loop without internet on Android?

Tags: java, android, javascript

I have a closed Wifi connection at my college without an internet connection. Two Android devices will be connected to that network. I need to be able to send and receive text messages between them, through an application. I believe it comes under P2P but most of my research is not helping me. I need to use that closed network and not any PAN like Bluetooth.
Note: Ideas on how to send push notifications, saying "Hello!", to the device on connecting to Wifi is also welcome.

Comment: Must you use a certain application (and are asking us how to configure your devices)? If so, please name it. Or are you asking us to recommend an application?